# hypothesis testing for population proportions

Tags: probability

A survey conducted by the ministry of health in 9% of parents described their children as overweight. Results from a study by University students claims that atleast 15% of parents described their children as overweight. You take a sample of 750 parents and that 68 out of the 750 described their children as overweight.

Q1. formulate and test the hypothesis that the proportion of parents who describe their children as overweight is less than the 15% claim by the University students.

So here my view is that this is a single population proportion with

P=  68/750 = 0.091 , n= 750 ,
π= 0.15 with π being the null hypothesized proportion

Ho : p =< 0
H1 : p> 0

the Z-stat =  (p-π)/ √ [ π(1-π)/ 750 ]
    (0.091-0.15) / √ [ 0.15(1-0.15)/ 750]

Z = 4.5

my Standard normal table does not give the corresponding value of 4.5 it shows up to Z= 3.9 so I cant find the P-value

somehow I think I misinterpreted the the data. it could be two population proportion.

please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your null hypothesis should be $H_0:p=0.15$ and the alternative hypothesis should be $H_1:p<0.15$.

The test statistic is $-4.55$ which means a vanishingly small $p$ value so reject $H_0$.

But check the question's wording again, because as it stands, the first sentence appears to have no relevance.